# How can I prevent a form action if my JavaScript functions have returned false?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very inexperienced with programming so sorry if this is stupid question.

I'm creating a form which the user will be able to submit using a button. I have used script functions to decide whether they will return true or false, with the only condition being that the input boxes must be filled. Here is a simplified version of my JavaScript and HTML code, I've only included one of the input boxes. (My real code has six)

```js
function validateEmail() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Email must be filled out");
        return false;
 }
 else {
  return true;
 }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" 
onsubmit="validateEmail()" method="post" action="Different_Page.html">
  
<label for="email">Email Address:</label>
<input type="email" name="email">
  
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The issue is that if the user does not type in their email and the function returns false, it still goes to the page I only want it to go to when it returns true. So in other words, I want it to do nothing and stay on this page, but ONLY when the script returns false. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to `return false` from the `onsubmit` function and not just from a function that that function calls.

```
onsubmit="return validateEmail()"
```

---

That said, modern code would avoid intrinsic event attributes in favour of binding event handlers with JavaScript …

```js
function validateEmail(evt) {
  var x = this.elements.email.value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("Email must be filled out");
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
}

document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener("submit", validateEmail);
```

```html
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="Different_Page.html">

  <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
  <input type="email" name="email">

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

---

… or forget JavaScript entirely and just use the validation features introduced in HTML 5.

```html
<form method="post" action="Different_Page.html">

  <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" required>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that last HTML solution is very simple. I didn't even need to use JavaScript after all.